# Is it possible to run a program that requires elevation unelevated

Tags: c++, c, winapi

My program normally needs to be launched as an elevated process and therefore it contains the usual manifest (`...<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"/>...`), so the UAC will pop up when the program is launched. This work fine as intended.

Now under certain conditions I'd like to run that program (programmatically from another unelevated process) as an unelevated process (IOW it should act just as if the manifest would not contain `level="requireAdministrator"`).

Is this possible?

Comment: `highestAvailable` - _"...Recommended for mixed-mode applications. ..."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756929(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @RichardCritten that's not quite what I need, because `highestAvailable` will not trigger the UAC dialog when you launch it from a standard (non admin) user.

Comment: @Jabberwocky You can do as Richard says and then, when you want to run it elevated, use the "Run as Administrator" command from explorer. I really can't see how you avoid some sort of interaction to get it elevated sometimes, and not elevated sometimes.

Comment: @AdrianMole that doesn't work out either. I rather want the contrary: I want to launch the program unelevated only programmatcally from another different unelevated program (via some ShellExecute/CreateProcess/or whatever magic, like some "run as non administator"). The behaviour when the program is clicked by the user is already what I want.

Comment: ... then you'll *have* to do it some other way then by adding that bit it the manifest. With that, you are saying that the program can **only** ever be run elevated. There are (I'm fairly sure) WinAPI calls you can make to check and/or set a process' elevation.

Comment: @AdrianMole thanks, I feared an answer like that. `highestAvailable` is mandatory, because the UAC must showup when the prgram is double clicked. So it looks as it cannot be done at all.

Comment: Not something that I have ready code for but there's [this CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320748/Elevating-During-Runtime) blog that *seems* to do what you want, in a roundabout sort of way. Any answer I posted would be, essentially, plagiarizing that.

Comment: Not entirely trivial, but [The COM Elevation Moniker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-com-elevation-moniker) allows you to request elevation at run time, e.g. in response to a command line argument. Kenny Kerr has an [article](https://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/Windows-Vista-for-Developers-_1320_-Part-4-_1320_-User-Account-Control) that covers this approach in detail. This isn't a dop-in replacement, but rather requires that you re-architect your application, moving the code that needs elevation into COM objects.

Comment: Have the program automatically relaunch itself elevated unless a particular command line argument is given.

Comment: @JonathanPotter that sounds promising, and it's really simple. I wonder why I didn't think of this myself. I'll check it out later.

Comment: You can launch an unelevated process as @RemyLebeau said but it's odd that under certain conditions you, other than users, would like to run that program as an unelevated process.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of clarity, lets call the program you want to run `X`.

I normally use a 'shim' to launch `X` elevated.  The shim is just a little program that is marked `requireAdministrator` and whose sole purpose is to run `X` elevated.  `X` is then marked `asInvoker` and will run elevated (only) when invoked from the shim.  You then make the shim the icon that the user clicks on.

Having done all that, you can then run `X` unelevated by launching it direct.

I hope that all makes sense!  I don't know of any other way.

Comment: Sounds very reasonable.

Comment: That make perfectly sense. But it's not really useful for my use case. I've thought about the "shim" method, but the thing is that I exactly wanted to avoid having a shim.

Comment: Why is that a problem?  It's about 10 lines of code.

Comment: @PaulSanders it's not a huge problem though, but JonathanPotte's comment above is probably what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Raymond Chen covered this topic on his [Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing) blog:

November 18th, 2013: [How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process and vice versa?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643)

> Going from an unelevated process to an elevated process is easy. You can run a process with elevation by passing the runas verb to Shell­Execute or Shell­Execute­Ex.
>
> **Going the other way is trickier.** For one thing, it’s really hard to munge your token to remove the elevation nature properly. And for another thing, even if you could do it, it’s not the right thing to do, because the unelevated user may be different from the elevated user.
>
> ...
>
> The solution here is to **go back to Explorer and ask Explorer to launch the program for you.** Since Explorer is running as the original unelevated user, the program (in this case, the Web browser) will run as Bob. This is also important in the case that the handler for the file you want to open runs as an in-process extension rather than as a separate process, for in that case, the attempt to unelevate would be pointless since no new process was created in the first place. (And if the handler for the file tries to communicate with an existing unelevated copy of itself, things may fail because of UIPI.)

April 25th, 2019: [How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process, redux](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190425-00/?p=102443)

> There’s another way which is a bit more direct, but it assumes that the thing you want to do can be done with a direct Create­Process call. In other words, if you need the system to look up the user’s file associations or default browser, then this technique is not for you.
>
> The idea is to take advantage of PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS access and the accompanying PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS process thread attribute:
>
> ...
>
> Basically, this lets you tell the Create­Process function, “Hey, like, um, pretend that other guy over there is creating the process.”

Both blog articles contain full source code examples.